# Reflection not displaying all the method of class

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-resources

I am trying to use reflection to invoke a method of Resources$Theme class but I am not able to do so.

Below is my code

```
Class inner=Class.forName("android.content.res.Resources$Theme");
            Constructor []ins=inner.getConstructors();
           // Method met=inner.getDeclaredMethod("newTheme", null);
            Method [] mer=inner.getMethods();
            for(Method m:mer){
                String name=m.getName();
                System.out.println(name);
            }
          // Object obj= met.invoke(null, null);

            for(Constructor con:ins){
                String name=con.getName();
                System.out.println(name);
            }
```

On Checking theme class I can see that newTheme(),getTheme and default constructor is available.
When I enable the first commented line it gives me error as NoSuchMethodFoundException. So tried to get all method name from class and I saw that it does not contain the few methods like newTheme(),getTheme(). 
Also my constructor list is coming as empty.

Can someone explain the reason behind it. I saw that one of the method(newTheme) is final and other(getTheme) has one annotation ( @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "theme", hasAdjacentMapping = true) . Is it because of this? If yes then what does the annotation means? 
Also why I do not see constructor list even when constructor is defined with   /*package*/ preceding. What does  /*package*/ means here?

Comment: Check the difference betweeen getMethods/getDeclaredMethods, same for constructors.

Comment: Even result of getDeclaredMethods does not contain method mentioned by me

Comment: Only difference is getMethods contain all object method like wait,notify also .

Comment: `newTheme()` is a member of `Resources` and not `Resources.Theme`. `getTheme()` is `@hide`-annotated - where are you running the code, actually?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [getDeclaredMethods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) and [getDeclaredConstructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors%28%29). Th* will return private, public, protected and package-protected methods, while [getMethods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) and [getConstructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) will return only public methods.

Also try iterating class hierarchy in the following way:

```
while (targetClass != null) {
    Method[] methods = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(setterMethodName, type);
    // do something with methods here 
    targetClass = targetClass.getSuperclass();
}
```

Comment: I checked but its not happening. Still i can not see the method mentioned by me.

Comment: Updated my answer. Iterate though the class hierarchy.